# Buffering Vertex Data in PyOpenGL

Tags: pyopengl

I have been using (modern: OpenGL 3.3) OpenGL in the past with C++ bindings. I have just started learning to use the python bindings. I have a program that runs but I am unable to get it to draw anything.

I am using 64 bit python 3.4 on a Windows 10 system.

It should be drawing a triangle. If I draw using GL_POINTS I can get a dot in the centre of the screen, with GL_TRIANGLES I get nothing.

I think the problem is with how I am buffering the data. I don't think that python is sending what I think it is sending because of the differences in memory management between C++ and python (I could be completely wrong and it might be something else).

`data` is supposed to be a pointer to a continuous block of memory containing the vertex data. I'm not sure how to achieve this in python (or even if this is how it should be done in pyopengl).

Here is the code I am using to generate the vertex position data and send it to OpenGL:

```
# Define some data, we will be drawing a triangle
vertices = [-1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
             0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
            +1.0, -1.0,  0.0]

data = (gl.GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)

vertex_array_object = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
gl.glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)

gl.glUseProgram(program)

# Create a buffer object
buffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (4*8)*3*3, data, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)     

gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

# Unbind the VAO
gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

I'd like a solution that doesn't use numpy. I am targeting windows platforms and all the advice (and experience) that I have gotten is that numpy does not play nicely with windows (no easy way to build; installer faulty etc.)

Here is the full program. Note: it requires the GLFW dll to run (for windows they have it available at http://www.glfw.org/download.html)

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl          #OpenGL
from pyglfw.libapi import *     # Window Toolkit - GLFW (Python libapi version)
import struct
import ctypes

glfwInit()

print(glfwGetVersion())

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

width = 600
height = 480
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, b'Hello GLFW (libapi)', None, None)

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)

glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_MOUSE_BUTTONS, gl.GL_TRUE)

def load_shaders():    
    program  = gl.glCreateProgram()

    vertex_shader   = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragment_shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    shader_file = open('VertexShader.glsl', 'r')        # open the file for reading
    vertex_shader_code = shader_file.read()             # read the whole file
    shader_file.close()                                 # close the file
    gl.glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vertex_shader_code)       # make that the source code

    shader_file = open('FragmentShader.glsl', 'r')
    fragment_shader_code = shader_file.read()
    gl.glShaderSource(fragment_shader, fragment_shader_code)
    shader_file.close()

    # Compile shaders
    gl.glCompileShader(vertex_shader)
    if gl.glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != gl.GL_TRUE:    # Check if compilation was successful
        info_log = gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader)
        raise RuntimeError('Vertex shader compilation failed: %s' % (info_log))
    else:
        print('Vertex shader compiled successfuly')

    gl.glCompileShader(fragment_shader)
    if gl.glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != gl.GL_TRUE:    # Check if compilation was successful
        info_log = gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader)
        raise RuntimeError('Fragment shader compilation failed: %s' % (info_log))
    else:
        print('Fragment shader compiled successfuly')

    gl.glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    gl.glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)

    gl.glLinkProgram(program)

    gl.glDetachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    gl.glDetachShader(program, fragment_shader)

    return program

#dark blue background
gl.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0);

# Get our shader program
program = load_shaders()

# Define some data, we will be drawing a triangle
vertices = [-1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
             0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
            +1.0, -1.0,  0.0]

data = (gl.GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)

vertex_array_object = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
gl.glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)

gl.glUseProgram(program)

# Create a buffer object
buffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (4*8)*3*3, data, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)     

gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

# Unbind the VAO
gl.glBindVertexArray(0)

while True:
    # Check the exit condition
    if glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS:
        break

    # Clear the screen
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    # Draw our triangle
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)
    gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)         #Starting from vertex 0, draw 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    gl.glBindVertexArray(0)

    glfwSwapBuffers(window)
    glfwPollEvents()

glfwTerminate()
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_FragColor.a = 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, I forgot to enable the attribute in the shader. The code above does work, it was just a case of me overlooking simpler solutions.

Comment: For the record, nuy works fine on Windows -- has for years. And it really is the right tool for this! There are some issues with an optimized BLAS for Win64 -- but you don't need that, and there are binary wheels on PyPi for es installation -- or you can use Anaconda and other distributions.